# Having error in Quick Sort Program

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, quicksort

Error " Pindex" was not declared in this scope. (Line 15)
Also, what is the difference between declaring the array in the function with

```
int a[]
```

and

```
int a*
```

And suggest some resources for explainatio of sorting algorithms.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int Partition(int a[], int start, int last);
void QuickSort(int a[], int start, int last)
{

/*if(start>=last)
{
   return ;
}*/
{    if(start<last)

  int Pindex=Partition(a, start, last);
  QuickSort(a, start, Pindex-1);
  QuickSort(a,Pindex+1, last);
}


}

int Partition(int a[] ,int start, int last)
{

int temp;
int Pindex=start;
 int pivot=a[last];
for (int i=0;i<last;i++)
{

    if(a[i]<=pivot)
    {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[Pindex];
        a[Pindex]=temp;
        Pindex++;
    }
}
temp=a[Pindex];
a[Pindex]=a[last];
a[last]=temp;
return Pindex;

}

int main()
{
 int n;
 cout<<"\n Enter the no of elements ";
 cin>>n;
 cout<<"\n Enter the elements ";
 int A[n];

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)

{

cin>>A[i];

}
QuickSort(A,0,n-1);
cout<<"\n Sorted Array ";

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{

    cout<<A[i];

}
return 0;


}
```

Comment: `Pindex` is only declared within the scope of `if` statement. This would be clear once you add braces: `if (start < last) { int Pindex=Partition(a, start, last); }`

Comment: As a function parameter, there is absolutely no difference between `int a[]` and `int* a`. You can even declare the function one way then define it the other way.

Comment: a*  will give an error. *a is a pointer.  a[10] is an array.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but the other two statements of Quicksort will also be valid only if (start<last). We also need to include them also otherwise Quicksort wont happen

Comment: Well, yes. Now you know what braces `{ }` are for.

Answer (score 1):

After looking in the provided source code, the main problem is located in the `Partition()` function. The local `int Pindex` in `QuickSort()` is no more a problem than using recursive call to cause a Segmantation Fault.

> In the troubleshooter function `int Partition(int a[] ,int start, int
>   last)`, the input arguments are `start` and `last`, but the for-loop,
>   where `Pindex` is incremented continues to be `for (int
>   i=0;i<last;i++)` and will cause a `Pindex` greater than `last` and the
>   last inversion `a[Pindex]=a[last];` will cause a write error.

The for-loop shall be done on the same range of the input arguments as follow:

```
int Partition(int a[] ,int start, int last)
{
    int temp;
    int Pindex=start;
    int pivot=a[last];
    // for-loop to the range [start;last[
    for (int i=start;i<last;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=pivot)
        {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[Pindex];
            a[Pindex]=temp;
            Pindex++;
        }
    }
    temp=a[Pindex];
    a[Pindex]=a[last];
    a[last]=temp;
    return Pindex;
}
```

Then all is working when correcting the QuickSort typo.

```
void QuickSort(int a[], int start, int last)
{
    /*if(start>=last) // to be deleted
    {
    return ;
    }*/
    if(start<last) {
        int Pindex=Partition(a, start, last);
        QuickSort(a, start, Pindex-1);
        QuickSort(a,Pindex+1, last);
    }
}
```